# Elasticsearch geo search strange behavior

Tags: java, elasticsearch, geometry, geospatial, elasticsearch-5

A few days ago I faced with the strange behavior of geo search in Elasticsearch.

I use AWS managed ES 5.5, obviously over REST interface.

Assume we have 200k objects with location info represented as the point only. I use geo search to find the points within multiple polygons. They are shown on the image below. Coordinates were extracted from final request to the ES. 
[image: polygons]
The request is built using official Java High-level REST client. The request query will be attached below.

I want to search for all objects within at least **one** polygon.
Here is the query (real fields names and values were replaced by stub, **Except** location and locationPoint.coordinates)

```
{
  "size" : 20,
  "query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "terms" : {
                "field1" : [
                  "a",
                  "b",
                  "c",
                  "d",
                  "e",
                  "f"
                ],
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "field2" : {
                  "value" : "q",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range" : {
                "field3" : {
                  "from" : "10",
                  "to" : null,
                  "include_lower" : true,
                  "include_upper" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range" : {
                "field4" : {
                  "from" : "10",
                  "to" : null,
                  "include_lower" : true,
                  "include_upper" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_shape" : {
                "location" : {
                  "shape" : {
                    "type" : "geometrycollection",
                    "geometries" : [
                      {
                        "type" : "multipolygon",
                        "orientation" : "right",
                        "coordinates" : [
                          [
                            // coords here
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "type" : "polygon",
                        "orientation" : "right",
                        "coordinates" : [
                          [
                            // coords here
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "type" : "polygon",
                        "orientation" : "right",
                        "coordinates" : [
                          [
                            // coords here
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "type" : "polygon",
                        "orientation" : "right",
                        "coordinates" : [
                          [
                            // coords here
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "relation" : "intersects"
                },
                "ignore_unmapped" : false,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "_source" : {
    "includes" : [
      "field1",
      "field2",
      "field3",
      "field4",
      "field8"
    ],
    "excludes" : [ ]
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "field1" : {
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg1" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field1",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg2" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field2",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg3" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field3",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg4" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field4",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg5" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field5",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg6" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field6",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg7" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field7",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "agg8" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field8",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "map_center" : {
      "geo_centroid" : {
        "field" : "locationPoint.coordinates"
      }
    },
    "map_bound" : {
      "geo_bounds" : {
        "field" : "locationPoint.coordinates",
        "wrap_longitude" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**, that field *location* is mapped as *geo_shape* and field *location.coordinates* is mapped as *geo_point*.

**So the problem is next.** Below the results (hits count) of requests are presented. Only polygons are changing.

```
#  Polygons                              Hits count

1) 1,2,3,4                               5565

2) 1                                     4897

3) 3,4                                   75

4) 2                                     9

5) 1,3,4                                 5543

6) 1,2                                   5466

7) 2,3,4                                 84
```

So, if I add results of polygon 1st with 2,3,4 polygons I will not obtain the number as it was in full request.

For example, *#1 != #2 + #7*, also *#1 != #5 + #4*, **but** *#7 == #4 + #3*

I cannot understand whether it is the issue in this request or expected behavior or even bug in ES.

Can anyone help me to understand the logic of such ES behavior or point to the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short conversation with Elasticsearch team member, we come up to AWS.
Build hashes of AWS and pure ES is not equal so, ES is modified by AWS team and we do not know exact changes. There can be some changes that might affect search in posted question.
Need to reproduce this behavior on pure ES cluster before we will continue our conversation.